# problem cleaning characters/str from a column and make it an int

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this function to clean the + and , out of a column:

```py
def data_clean_installs(x):
    if '+' in x:
        return float(x.replace('+',''))
    elif ',' in x:
        return float(x.replace(',',''))
    else:
        return float(x)
```

I want to use the function to make a new int column called 'Clean_Installs' and ran this:

```py
apr['Clean_Installs'] = apr.Installs.astype('str').apply(data_clean_installs).apply(int)
```

and get this `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10,000'`

I tried everything I can think of, too much to put here and will take any inputs please... Oh, I am new and this is my first question ever. Sorry if I violated any rules... Really hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Aside, ideally your function should only have *one* `return` statement.  Many devs (myself included) would have your head if they end up maintaining your code (later in your career).  You’ve been warned.  ;-)

Comment: @S3DEV that's disingenous. There's nothing wrong with having multiple return statements in a function. OP's case goes a little overboard, sure, but your comment makes it sound like bad practice, which would be an unfair generalization.

Comment: @ddejohn - You’re absolutely correct (and I agree) it’s not *wrong*.  However, it generally should trigger a thought process that ‘there’s likely a better way to structure this function/method’.

Comment: Agreed, I think that's a more appropriate message.

Comment: @Dan I've added the `pandas` tag to your post. Remember to tag your posts as best you can so that they're easier to find, and so they show up in people's feeds!

Comment: Ok thanks! If I am tracking, I should not write a function for a specific reason ... While I would have never thought of it at this point, I think I see the improvements in the code below and they BOTH WORKED!  I really appreciate the explanation from everyone too! Thanks S3DEV - ddejohn - Thomas Q - tzinie!

Answer (score 3):

No need for a custom function here since you seem to already be using Pandas:

```py
apr.Installs.str.replace("[,+]", "", regex=True).apply(int)
```

My only concern with using `.apply(int)` is that it'll fail in the case you have values in the column that won't translate to integers, like `"1,000.53"`.

For a little bit of an explanation, `regex=True` is telling Pandas that the pattern (the first argument in `Series.str.replace`) should be treated as a [regular expression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

The square brackets in the pattern `[,+]` form what's known as a character class. The pattern is basically telling Pandas, "use regex to match any string containing *any* of these characters, `","` or `"+"` or both, and replace them with the empty string.

Regex is super powerful, but there's a time and a place for it. This is one of those times!

Comment: Keeping it simple, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `10,000` used to be `+10,000` or something like that. In the function `data_clean_installs` you try to convert if a `+` is found, but there also is a `,` in there. Your function should look like this:

```py
def data_clean_installs(x):
    return float(x.replace('+', '').replace(',', ''))
```

You don't need to check if `x` has a `+` or a `,`, the replace will already to that for you and will convert it to `''` automatically.

Also if you are converting it to int afterwards you can replace the `float` call with an `int` call in the `data_clean_installs` if all values are guaranteed to be integers

Comment: Perhaps use `str.translate` rather than multiple `replace` calls.

Comment: @S3DEV `x.translate({ord("+"): None, ord(","): None})` is way cleaner than 2 replaces in a row. Totally not unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @ThomasQ or `x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '+,'))` which is a bit cleaner than using a dictionary, besides takes less space if you need to expand

Comment: Yep, the 3-arg form of `str.maketrans` is definitely the cleanest approach in the case that the operation might need to be performed many times (where saving the translation table would be ideal: `t = str.maketrans("", "", ",+")` and then using `some_string.translate(t)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import re

apr['Clean_Installs'] = apr.Installs.apply(lambda x: int(re.sub('[+,]', '', x)))
```